# How to destruct class with mutex member?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a class with a `std::shared_mutex` member protecting some resource the class owns (say, a vector). My problem is that during destruction of the class, a different thread may be holding the mutex. Destruction of the class then causes a crash. A solution seems to be to acquire the mutex at the class destructor (it hasn't crashed yet), but is that a solution that guarantees safety? Or could another thread swoop in again between the lock being released as the destructor body ends and the class being fully destructed (members still need to be destructed after destructor body ends)? And i guess its also a problem if another thread is waiting to acquire the mutex while the class is being destructed?

Comment: this isn't really about mutexes, its about lifetime management, destructing an object whilst something else holds a reference to it is a bad idea, you might want to use `std::shared_ptr` to help manage the lifetime of the object better. For help with your specific use case a [mre] would make your question easier to answer

Comment: The thread should extend the lifetime of the object or the destructor should synchronize with threads still refering to it. One option is to create a shared pointer to the object, and pass a copy of that to the thread that's using it.

Comment: If you take a `std::unique_lock` on your `std::shared_mutex` before destroying the object, that will guarantee all other locks are released.

Comment: @Galik good to know, but then we still have the problem that other threads may be waiting to acquire the lock. Alan and Pepijn make good points, I need to rethink deeper...